# Locking multiple mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm wondering if it's possible to lock multiple mutexes at the same time, like:

```
 Mutex1.Lock();
 {
     Mutex2.Lock();
     {
          // Code locked by mutex 1 and 2.
     }
     Mutex2.Unlock();

     // Code locked by mutex 1.
 }
 Mutex1.Unlock();
```

It would be very useful for some situations. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Just be careful, doing so without the proper diligence can easily lead to deadlocks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible but the order of locking must be consistent throughout the application otherwise deadlock is a likely result (if two threads acquire the locks in opposite order then each thread could be waiting on the other to release one of the locks).

Recommend using a scoped lock and unlock facility for exception safety, to ensure locks are always released ([`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) with [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for example):

```
std::mutex mtx1;
std::mutex mtx2;

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mtx1_lock(mtx1);
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mtx2_lock(mtx2);
    {
    }
}
```

If your compiler does not support these C++11 features boost has similar in [`boost::mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) and [`boost::lock_guard`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.lock_guard).

Comment: I'm using pthreads, is it possible to protect my program from deadlocks without using c++11? I'm using pthread_mutex_lock and unlock inside the .Lock() and .Unlock() functions.

Comment: @grimgrom, yes it is. The `lock_guard` is mentioned as it makes exception safety much simpler to achieve but it is not required to avoid deadlocks. To avoid deadlocks ensure the locks are always acquired in the same order and _always_ released, regardless of how the code following the lock acquisition exits.

Comment: @grimgrom, note you could easily write your own `Lock_guard` class for your `Mutex` class. Just `Lock()` in the constructor and `Unlock()` in the destructor. Just be sure that `Lock_guard` stores a reference to the `Mutex` instance and does not copy it.

Comment: How come there would be any difference if I use an additional class called Lock_guard instead of just using my Mutex class. I mean, I'm just calling Lock/Unlock in both cases?

Comment: It makes handling exceptions simpler, that's all.

Comment: ok I see, so is this a valid and safe way of doing it? : http://pastebin.com/aXUEWQpX

Comment: @grimgrom: one thing that a lock guard implementation will typically do is to test if the mutex is actually locked before unlocking it in the destructor (so the mutex class needs to track and provide a method to get the state of the mutex). That way if the user explicitly unlocks the mutex for whatever reason, the destructor won't redundantly unlock it (which would result in undefined behavior).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, FWIW I consider that a bug in the calling code and I would (and have) not check if the mutex is locked. If the lock guard is constructed then the mutex is locked. Any outside interference is, as you say, undefined behaviour just as destruction of the referenced mutex object is.

Comment: If code somewhere else locks `mtx2` before `mtx1`, concurrently with this code locking `mtx1` then `mtx2`, then lock guards won't save you, it will deadlock. Both threads will wait forever for the other guy to release the one they need. That is what the beginning of this answer mentioned, but seems to have been buried by RAII discussion. The deadlock is the main issue with multiple locks.

Comment: This example is unsafe, as doug65536 already mentioned, unless you can guarantee everytime these mutexes are locked, they are always locked in the same order (good luck with that). The absolutely safe way to do it is to use std::lock, as proposed by Pubby.

Answer (score 46):

`std::lock` seems to exist for this purpose.

> Locks the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock.
>   The objects are locked by an unspecified series of calls to lock, try_lock, unlock. If a call to lock or unlock results in an exception, unlock is called for any locked objects before rethrowing.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock

Answer (score 36):

C++17 also provides `scoped_lock` for the specific purpose of locking multiple mutexes that prevents deadlock in a RAII style, similar to `lock_guard`.

```
#include<mutex>

std::mutex mtx1, mtx2;
void foo()
{
    std::scoped_lock lck{mtx1, mtx2};
    // proceed
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately current gcc v5.4 which is default in ubuntu has no support for std::scoped_lock yet. Boost analog could be used though.