# C++ overriding operator for a class whose object accessed by multiple thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to overload operator=, operator == for a container class as shown below. The container class object can be access from multiple thread.

```
Container& operator=(const Container &other)
{
   // assign this->variable = other.variable
}
```

I have created two container objects as shown below

```
Container objectA, objectB.
```

if i do `objectA = objectB` from any one of the thread, is it safe to take
mutex for both objectA, objectB inside the overloaded operator= () function as shown below.

```
Container& operator=(const Container &other)
{
    // take objectA mutex.
    // take objectB mutex.
   // assign this->variable = other.variable
   // release objectB mutex.
   // release objectA mutex.
}
```

If there is any recommended or standard way kindly let me know.

Comment: Instead of a mutex, you may get better preference with a [read-write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock).

Comment: See: [Locking multiple mutexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483767/locking-multiple-mutexes)  One important takeaway here is that you want to employ mechanisms (e.g., [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) as mentioned in the link) to avoid explicitly needing to release the mutex objects.  Aside from convenience, this improves the [Exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) of your code.

Comment: One recurring feature of multithreaded code is that no function or object can completely protect itself from concurrent access.   In your case, the grabbing of mutexes needs to happen in the caller of your `operator=()` (grab them before, release them after).

Answer (score 1):

I see a deadlock scenario with your approach:

```
//Thread1:
x = y;

// Thread2:
y = x;
```

which can happen like this:

```
order:
T1: take x.mutex
T2: take y.mutex
T1: take y.mutex (can't, waiting)
T2: take x.mutex (can't, waiting)

oups
```

Comment: [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) can be a possible remedy to that (assuming the OP uses `<mutex>`, and not another threading library).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a thread master, but if you don't use mutex you'll have some suprise. You can have one mutex per thread, or you can have a mutex for the all the needed variable for your copy

```
For exemple, here we supposed you need to copy both A & B variable
from the "Other" Container instance

std::mutex ex1 //Mutex for var A & B for your "$this" instance
std::mutex ex2 //Mutex for var A & B for your Other instance

Container& operator=(const Container &other)
{
 ex1.lock();
 ex2.lock();
 $this->A = other.getA();
 $this->B = other.getB();
 ex1.unlock();
 ex2.unlock();
}
```

Just use mutex on "logical" variable, if A, B and C are dependent (or used at the same time), create a mutex for them and not a mutex for your class :)