# Mutex lock and unlock sequence

Tags: mutex

Does it make sense to use the following mutex example or should I unlock 'A' first and then lock 'B'?

```
mtx.lock(A);
mtx.lock(B);
//code
mtx.unlock(A);
mtx.unlock(B);
```

And if i used it as described what could be the problem?

Comment: This is about C++ mutexes, right? Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483767/14344821

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple mutexes, you can lock and unlock them separately.
You must always be wary of 1) *deadlocks* and 2) *the possibility of exceptions* that prevent the mutex unlocking from occurring

```
try{
    mtx.lock(A);
    THREAD_CALLS_FUNCTION(S) // Woops... an exception is thrown
    mtx.unlock(A); // not happening.
{ catch (...)
{
    (...) // but this is executed, mutex remains locked
}
```

There are a few more risks, see https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/the-risk-of-mutexes.

A good practice is to use mutexes in combination with *locks* (probably  a `std::lock_guard`). They encapsulate mutexes in a more safe way w.r.t. deadlocks. This is discussed more elaborately [here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/prefer-locks-to-mutexes).